# how to get two elements from a list each time in common-lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

For `((1 2) (3 4) (5 6))`, you can use `loop for (a b) in '((1 2) (3 4) (5 6))` to get a = 1, b = 2 each time.

But for `'(1 2 3 4)`, I try to do `loop for x on '(1 2 3 4) by #'cddr for a = (car x) for b = (cadr x)` to get a = 1, b = 2.

Is there a better way to do such thing?

Comment: Does this do what you want?  Are you just looking for a clearer way to express it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try `for ... on`:

```
(loop for (a b) on '(1 2 3 4) by #'cddr collect (cons a b))
```